# How to turn `logging` warnings into errors?

Tags: python, logging

A library that I use emits warnings and errors through the `logging` module (`logging.Logger`'s `warn()` and `error()` methods).  I would like to implement an option to turn the warnings into errors (i.e., fail on warnings).

Is there an easy way to achieve this?

From looking at the documentation, I cannot see a ready-made solution.  I assume it is possible by adding a custom `Handler` object, but I am not sure how to do it "right".  Any pointers?

Comment: Can you provide a link to the library's code if it is freely available?

Comment: @hoefling sorry, no, it's proprietary.

Comment: Please clarify which you want:  1)  turn logging warnings into logging errors, or 2) turn both logging warnings and errors into *exceptions raised*.

Comment: @wim The former, but the latter would also be acceptable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: I like the proposal of [Vinay](https://stackoverflow.com/users/118903/vinay-sajip) made in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47424657/2650249), injecting a custom `Filter` instead of a `Handler` is a much cleaner way. Please check it out!

---

You are on the right track with implementing own `Handler`. This is pretty easy to implement. I would do it like that: write a handler that edits the `LogRecord` in-place and attach one handler instance to the library's root loggers. Example:

```
# library.py

import logging


_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)


def library_stuff():
    _LOGGER.warning('library stuff')
```

This is a script that uses the library:

```
import logging
import library


class LevelRaiser(logging.Handler):

    def emit(self, record: logging.LogRecord):
        if record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            record.levelno = logging.ERROR
            record.levelname = logging.getLevelName(logging.ERROR)


def configure_library_logging():
    library_root_logger = logging.getLogger(library.__name__)
    library_root_logger.addHandler(LevelRaiser())


if __name__ ==  '__main__':

    # do some example global logging config
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

    # additional configuration for the library logging
    configure_library_logging()

    # play with different loggers
    our_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    root_logger = logging.getLogger()

    root_logger.warning('spam')
    our_logger.warning('eggs')

    library.library_stuff()

    root_logger.warning('foo')
    our_logger.warning('bar')

    library.library_stuff()
```

Run the script:

```
WARNING:root:spam
WARNING:__main__:eggs
ERROR:library:library stuff
WARNING:root:foo
WARNING:__main__:bar
ERROR:library:library stuff
```

Note that warning level is elevated to error level only on library's logging prints, all the rest remains unchanged.

Answer (score 7):

@hoefling's answer is close, but I would change it like so:

```
class LevelRaiser(logging.Filter):
    def filter(self, record):
        if record.levelno == logging.WARNING:
            record.levelno = logging.ERROR
            record.levelname = logging.getLevelName(logging.ERROR)
        return True

def configure_library_logging():
    library_root_logger = logging.getLogger(library.__name__)
    library_root_logger.addFilter(LevelRaiser())
```

The reason is that filters are used to change `LogRecord` attributes and filter stuff out, whereas handlers are used to do I/O. What you're trying to do here isn't I/O, and so doesn't really belong in a handler.

Comment: Indeed, this answer fits more in the `logging` concept than mine and should be the accepted one! I updated my answer with a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign `logging.warn` to `logging.error` before calling methods from your library:

```
import logging
warn_log_original = logging.warn
logging.warn = logging.error
library_call()
logging.warn = warn_log_original
```

Comment: This is dangerous as it will turn any warning into error, regardless who emitted it.

Comment: I have to agree that this is a bit of a hack, but it might actually work for me.

Comment: Updated my answer to make logger hack more isolated to library stuff. However @hoefling solution looks like a much better way to solve this problem :).

Answer (score 0):

To use a specific example, I have used this pattern to catch `.env` parsing errors, by turning logging warnings into errors.  Like this:

```py
import warnings
import logging
import dotenv

class WarningHandler(logging.Handler):
    def emit(self, record):
        warnings.warn(record.getMessage())

# Treat dotenv logger warnings as real warnings
logging.getLogger("dotenv.main").addHandler(WarningHandler())

# Treat warnings as exceptions (which will halt the program)
warnings.filterwarnings("error")

# Try loading the `.env`
dotenv.load_dotenv()
```

If there is a parsing problem, then the program will halt as desired after a line like this:

```bash
Python-dotenv could not parse statement starting at line 109
```